# The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I used the code example from the official RTK query documentation

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced

I am trying to get 30 users from database but for some reason my console is giving me this error for every user: (The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation. The entity that was passed)

Help me understand where (selectId) came from

It's about the getAllUsers request on line 22.

apiSlice.js

```
import {
  createSelector,
  createEntityAdapter
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from '../apiSlice';

const usersAdapter = createEntityAdapter()
const initialState = usersAdapter.getInitialState()

export const extendedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: (pagination) => ({
        url: `/user/pagination/${pagination}`,
      }),
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'Post', id }],
    }),

    getAllUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => '/user/all',
      transformResponse: (res) => {
        return usersAdapter.setAll(initialState, res)
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUsersQuery, useGetAllUsersQuery } = extendedApiSlice;

export const selectUsersResult = extendedApiSlice.endpoints.getAllUsers.select()

const selectUsersData = createSelector(
  selectUsersResult,
  (usersResult, selectId) => usersResult.data
)

export const {
  selectAll: selectAllUsers,
  selectById: selectUserById,
} = usersAdapter.getSelectors((state) => selectUsersData(state) ?? initialState)
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { App } from './app';
import { store } from './store/store';
import { extendedApiSlice } from './store/friends/friendsApi';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const el = document.getElementById('root');
if (el === null) throw new Error('Root container missing in index.html');

store.dispatch(extendedApiSlice.endpoints.getAllUsers.initiate());

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

Сalling selectAllUsers in the component

```
const allUsers = useAppSelector(selectAllUsers);
console.log(allUsers);
```

[image: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRZTt.png)]

[image: [This solution didn't work for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4EmW.png)]

Comment: Please share code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity adapter default expects the entity to have `id` for unique identification. In your case, as i can see, unique id of the user id named as `_id`.

Try the following way of explicitly setting the id:

```
const usersAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (user) => user._id,
});
```

Hopefully, that should fix the issue.

Thanks.